# How do I create a url pattern like controller/action/id in django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to create a url pattern that will behave like controller/action/id route in rails. So far here is what I have :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
import views

urlpatterns = ('',
              (r'^(?P<app>\w+)/(?P<view>\w+)/$', views.select_view),
              )
```

Here is my 'views.py':

```
def select_view(request, app, view):
    return globals()['%s.%s', % (app, view,)]()
```

So far this hasn't worked. I get a key error exception in the 'globals' function. Am I going in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from django.utils.importlib import import_module

def select_view(request, app, view):
    mod = import_module('%s.views' % app)
    return getattr(mod, view)(request)
```

It is obviously oversimplified example, what you do is import `views.py` from your app and see if it has `view` function, and if it does execute that function giving request as the first argument.

See some examples of how Django does it with [`get_callable`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L74) and [`autodiscover`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py) methods.